# How do I append an executeFetchRequest result into a array struct

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm an iOS newbie developer. I'm trying to import the results of an executeFetchRequest into a structure I created for viewing later into a table. I"m getting "Array index out of range" in func getTasks(), I'm pretty sure I"m supposed to append it, but not sure quite how.

I'm sure there's a better way of setting this up in general. Right now I'm just trying to get things to work. But other suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var taskMgr: TaskManager = TaskManager()

struct task {
    var name = "Un-Named"
    var desc = "Un-Described"
}

class TaskManager: NSObject {

    var tasks = task[]()

    init() {
        super.init()
        self.getTasks()
    }

    func addTask(name: String, desc: String) {

        tasks.append(task(name: name, desc: desc))

        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Tasks", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        var newTask = Tasks(entity: ent, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        newTask.name = name
        newTask.desc = desc

        println("Object saved")

        context.save(nil)
    }

    func getTasks() {
        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tasks")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

        var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

        if (results.count > 0) {
            self.tasks = task[]()
            var i = 0
            for element in results {
                tasks[i].name = element.name  // fatal error: Array index out of range
                tasks[i].desc = element.desc
                i++
            }
        }
    }

}

class  Tasks: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var desc: String
}
```

Comment: In Swift (as in Objective-C) type names should be title case -- your code will be more understandable if you rename your struct from `task` to `Task`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use subscripting to add items to an array -- you need to call `append()` or use the `+=` operator instead. Try this:

```
self.tasks = task[]()
for element in results {
    tasks += task(name: element.name, desc: element.desc)
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks for your patience with me newbieness. I'll let you know.